# PROBLEMAS SOBRE CONEXION MYSQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mysqli, express

hola tengo un problemas sobre un trabajo que quiero hacer y me da problemas sobre la conecxion y el error que me da en el terminal es este 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dice que no tiene conecxion de autenficacion del servidor 
el codigo de la llave servidor

```js
module.exports = {
    database: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '1234',
        port: '3306',
        database: 'database_links',
        insecureAuth: true,


    }
};
```

el codigo de la consulta es

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    res.render('links/add');
});

router.post('/add', async(req, res) => {
    const { title, url, description } = req.body;
    const newLink = {
        title,
        url,
        description
    };
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO links set ?', [newLink]);
    res.send('received');

});

module.exports = router;
```

y como estoy usando el programa mysql desde el pc al mirar la configuración del mi tabla y mi mysql para ver la direccion de mi configuracion es la misma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al no ser que se me ha olvidado algo .
agradeceria cualquier ayuda

Comment: Hay un problema de compatibilidad con el protocolo de autentificación de MySQL 8.0 y el que implementa NodeJS. Tal vez esta respuesta de S.O. [NodeJS can't authenticate with MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0), te de algo de orientación. Saludos

Comment: Voy ha probar más tarde lo mismo que hizo la consulta  haciendo <CRÉATE USER > otra pregunta y quizás me digais  este hombre es nuevo . Si  que lo soy  . Esto se hace de la consola. No?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la consola de MySQL? Si, puedes hacerlo desde la consola o usando tu Administrador de Base de Datos preferido.

Comment: Ya lo solucione la conexión ahora me guarda en la bases de datos

Answer (score 0):

tengo un problema a la hora de ver el enlace de que me mandaste Mauricio he optado en hacer lo que han dicho hacer 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass' o 
bien crear 
CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';

desde el terminal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
me da problemas y no se que estoy haciendo mal,
:(

Comment: Hola, este espacio es para respuestas, si ya encontraste la solución, puedes publicarla como respuesta y la marcas válida. Si esta no es la respuesta válida, te sugiero que la elimines para evitar confusiones. Recuerda redactar bien tu respuesta, para que ayude a otros que tengan el mismo problema. Saludos

Comment: es que soy nuevo  no se como marcarlos no es la primera vez que me pasa